# Relation and differences between Awe, Aha moment and Flow

Tags: terminology, motivation, positive-psychology, flow

Relation and differences between Awe, Aha moment and Flow?

From my reading, Awe is defined as 'Awe refers to an intense emotional response people may have when they encounter an object, event, or person that is extraordinary.', which is very similar to Aha moments.

And also Awe is also described as 'Awe can be characterized as an experience of immense perceptual vastness that coincides with an increase in focus.', which is similar to flow.

So I wonder what are the relation between all these?

Comment: I'm not really sure what sort of answer you are looking for...  Different emotions often have shared features - for example, both fear and excitement can feature a fast heartbeat.  While I'm sure the 3 emotions/states in this question have some shared features, they are also different.  If you are just looking for definitions of these states, then have you tried looking on Google?  Where have you run into confusion?